# Cannot consume Talend Soap API

Tags: web-services, soap, talend

I am trying to use the Tsoap component within Talend to consume the API. I have tried the Soap UI Client (separate application) and was able to get the response. 
However within the Tsoap component within the Soap Message, I have pasted the sample request and I get an error eery single time. Can anyone help!

```
" <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
xmlns=\"http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5\">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                   <GetSites>
                      <Request>
                         <SourceCredentials>
                            <SourceName>Test235</SourceName>
                            <Password>3IERKOFDNFEOFMKDFOEMFD=</Password>
                            <SiteIDs>
                               <int>-99</int>
                            </SiteIDs>
                         </SourceCredentials>
                         <XMLDetail>Full</XMLDetail>
                         <PageSize>0</PageSize>
                         <CurrentPageIndex>0</CurrentPageIndex>
                      </Request>
                   </GetSites>
                </soapenv:Body>
             </soapenv:Envelope>"
```

What am I doing wrong?? Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the error what you are getting?

Try this if you haven't done (just a guess)

--> If you are using and HTTPS web service then make sure to setup the authentication( I used Trust serve with SLL and provided the keystore file path and password)

Comment: Sorry...I am a newbiew to Talend...so you will have to elaborate. Where do I get the Keystore file path and password from? How do I know it's an https web service? I think it is now that you mention it.

Comment: When you said you executed the same in SOAP UI.. you might be hitting an URL or WSDL right? check whether that is http or https? and can you send me your error if possible.